# Fetching data value defined in the select tag when an option is selected

Tags: javascript

I have the following markup and I need to fetch value of `data-base` inside the function below.

```
<select id="myid" onclick="myselected(this)" data-base="/admin/index">
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function myselected(obj) {

  var idx = obj.selectedIndex;
  var ival = obj.options[idx].value;

   var baseval = .... ? how do I access data-base value?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute):

```
var baseval = obj.getAttribute('data-base')
```